# Selecting a drop down item using space key using Jquery in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        $(this).keydown(function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode ===32) 
           {

           }
         }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CWvwn/

In the following fiddle i have noticed that you can't choose an item by pressing space key in FireFox. It works in other browsers though. Is there a jquery way to force the item to be selected using space key (something like i wrote above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible with the example code below. I have tested it with Firefox.

I haven't found any other solution, but it works. You can find the same code at jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/CWvwn/3287/).

```js
$(function () {
    $('select').on('keyup', function (event) {
        //console.log(event);   
        if (event.keyCode == '32') {
            var selected = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
            //console.log(selected);
            $("select").prop('selectedIndex', selected);
            $(this).blur();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```